# Interview question about "largest range" makes no sense

Tags: seq

Here's the question. I'm actually dumbfounded. I don't even get the question. What are they on about?

[image: Screenshot of the question]

What even is a *largest range*? What do they mean by *largest*? What's a *range*? They say a *range* is a collection of numbers that come right after each other in the set of real integers. Okay, so *1, 2, 3, 4*, stuff like that, right? But then they say the numbers need not be ordered or even adjacent.... **but then they're not coming right after each other!!** They are contradicting their own previous statement. Now I have no idea what a range is.

Their example doesn't help either. Why is *[0, 15, 5, 2, 4, 10, 7]* the largest range in that vector?

What is going on?

Comment: No, because if you ignore 15, 5, and 10, you get [0, 2, 4, 7]. They do not "come right after each other in the set of real integers", which is what they literally write. Unless you think [2] comes right after [0]??And  [7] comes right after [4]???

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear in the question, but I'm pretty sure the interviewer means a "range" is a set of consecutive numbers (n, n+1).

The range [0,7] is actually [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] since all of those appear in the full set.

The actual order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you were given in the interview, which you list in your question as well, the input array is: `[1, 11, 3, 0, 15, 5, 2, 4, 10, 7, 12, 6]`. The reason that the "largest range" is identified as `[0, 7]` is because all the numbers between `0` and `7` are included in that array.

There isn't another range in the input array that has a longer range than 0 to 7. For instance, there is a [10, 12] range in the input array, but that array has a length of 3 that is smaller than the length of [0, 7] range, which is 8.

In this case, the range is understood as a continuous list of integers, the largest range is the list with the most number of integers.

Answer (score 0):

It means

> Find the largest continuous range of numbers

For eg. in array `[0,1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

There are 2 continuous list
`[0,1,2]` and `[5,6,7,8,9,10]` but as the larger range is the second one. so the output must be `[5,10]`.

i.e. The largest and smallest of the largest range.